# Browser crashes when binding a foreign source datafield in jqx.dataAdapter

Tags: javascript, jqxwidgets

I'm trying to build a grid using jQWidgets (jqxGrid) with a column which displays values from a foreign data source, using jqx.dataAdapter, but the browser crashes when I try to call the dataBind() method.

Here's my (browser crashing!) jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qYyRs/6/

Partial code:

```
            var Area_DataSource = {
                datatype: 'array',
                localdata: Area_Data,
                async: false,
                datafields: [{
                    name: 'Id'
                }, {
                    name: 'Name'
                },{
                    name: 'PlantId'
                },{
                    name: 'PlantName',
                    value: 'PlantId',
                    values: {
                        value: 'Value',   // the problematic field
                        name: 'Name',
                        source: Plant_DataAdapter.records
                    }
                }]
            };
            var Area_DataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(Area_DataSource);

            Area_DataAdapter.dataBind();  // booom!
```

Base example from jQWidgets website:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/gridkeyvaluescolumnwitharray.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed issue:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/browser-crashes-foreign-datafield-in-jqx-dataadapter/

> "We debugged the issue and confirm it. It will be resolved in jQWidgets
>   2.8.
>
> Best Regards, Peter Stoev
>
> jQWidgets Team http://www.jqwidgets.com"